# MySQL code to get one tables data, insert it into another and delete the old data

Tags: mysql

Info:
I need to create a MySQL code to select *more than one* lines of data from the table `items_rooms`, insert data into table `items_users` based from the data inside `items_rooms` THEN delete the data in `items_rooms`. But inside of that I need to also gather some data from another table `items` to grab the user Id of the owner who owns the item.

So in the end the only tables that have data are items and items_users, and they work from getting their data from `items_rooms`.

Seems confusing? I know, here is my code I wrote which I know is completely wrong but It might help you out.

```
$getItemRooms = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items_rooms WHERE room_id = '" . $roomid . "'");
    while($roomitem = $getItemRooms->fetch_assoc()) {

        $getItems = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE item_id = '" . $roomitem['item_id'] . "'");
        while($items = $getItems->fetch_assoc()) {

                $sql->query("INSERT INTO items_users (item_id, user_id) VALUES ('" . $roomitem['item_id'] . "', '" . $items['placedBy'] . "')");
                $sql->query("DELETE FROM items_rooms WHERE room_id = '" . $roomid . "'");
                echo 'done';

        }

    }
```

So for instance, `room_id` inside of `items_rooms` could be 3. inside `items_rooms` there are 10 rows if items that are owned. I need them items to be deleted and replaced into `items_users` but `items_rooms` does not have the owner id that `items` has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html), together with an appropriate join:

```
INSERT INTO items_users (item_id, user_id)
SELECT item_id, items.placedBy
FROM   items JOIN items_rooms USING (item_id)
WHERE  room_id = ?
```

If your application is subject to synchronous database access from multiple clients, be careful to avoid a race hazard arising between the `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements; in particular consider using a [locking read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) in the above statement and performing the `DELETE` statement within the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is grabbing data from items table try to retrieve all you need with one query using join.
For instance:

```
select *
from items_rooms as ir
inner join items as i on ir.item_id=i.item_id
where item_id = ...
```

It's better to specify only necessary fields from every table instead of using (*).
Also you can combine INSERT and SELECT statements into one query.
Try to look [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) 
It will simplify and speed up your php script